# не могу построить дерево категорий

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем.
Имеется такая вот структура у меня

- id — ключ категории
- parent_id — id родительской категории
- name – название раздела

Как по ней построить дерево категорий?

Comment: Вопрос, вобщем-то простой... А потому хочется спросить: что пытались сделать? Какие варианты рассматривали?

Comment: Поищите на этом же сайте. Я уже точно отвечал на такой вопрос. Возможно даже не раз. И справа в списке похожих вопросов был еще десяток

Comment: мне уже ответили и у меня все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  categories");
if   (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $cats = array();
    while($cat =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $cats_ID[$cat['id']][] = $cat;
        $cats[$cat['parent_id']][$cat['id']] =  $cat;
    }
}

function build_tree($cats,$parent_id,$only_parent = false){
    if(is_array($cats) and isset($cats[$parent_id])){
        $tree = '<ul>';
        if($only_parent==false){
            foreach($cats[$parent_id] as $cat){
                $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
                $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
                $tree .= '</li>';
            }
        }elseif(is_numeric($only_parent)){
            $cat = $cats[$parent_id][$only_parent];
            $tree .= '<li>'.$cat['name'].' #'.$cat['id'];
            $tree .=  build_tree($cats,$cat['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
        $tree .= '</ul>';
    }
    else return null;
    return $tree;
}
```

Comment: это похоже то что надо, сейчас проверю