# Мне сказали что такой подход не очень хорошо работает с деревом

Tags: php

Вчера я разобрался как работает дерево каталогов на php. Это было вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473815/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)
И вчера же я узнал что такой подход устарел, чем его лучше заменить и почему?

речь идет о переборе рекурсией и хранении самого дерева, а не то что php и mysql устарел.

Comment: судя по всему, "устарел" из-за `mysql_*`, а значит у вас дубликат [этого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448720/5079)

Comment: Да брехня всё это. Ничего не устарело, всё актуально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да есть несколько способов хранения деревьев, один из самых передовых на мой взгляд в Реляционных базах это `Nested Sets`

Comment: интересное название, а есть ли готовое решение все в одном? можно ссылку?

Comment: рекомендую этот класс http://forum.dklab.ru/viewtopic.php?t=27484, я на этом форуме в свое время в 2001 году начал изучать perl и их разработку "Денвер" по сей день использую

Comment: боьшое спасибо, ушел изучать